# Text not changing with Greensock Text Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsap

I'm trying to use the Greensock text plugin. I can change the color of text, but I cannot change the text. I'm using jQuery 3.2.1 and Greensock TweenMax 1.20.3

My code will change the text color to white, but the text will remain as `Test`. I'm not getting any console errors either.

```js
var myElement = $("#scramble");

TweenLite.to(myElement, 2, {
  text: "This is the new text",
  color: "#FFFFFF",
  ease: Linear.easeNone,
  paused: false
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<div id="scramble">Test</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You Need to add the Greensock TweenMax Text plugin.

```js
var myElement = $("#scramble");

TweenLite.to(myElement, 2, {
  text: "This is the new text",
  color: "red",
  ease: Linear.easeNone,
  paused: false
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.3/plugins/TextPlugin.min.js"></script>
<div id="scramble">Test</div>
```